# ¿Deberíamos mejorar los extractos de etiqueta para indicar cuándo usar en lugar de copiar la primera parte de su wiki?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, extracto-de-etiquetas

Estaba revisando la información que existe en las etiquetas, y viendo la ayuda acerca de que es: **La orientación de uso o extracto de wiki** se menciona

> La orientación de uso o extracto de wiki de etiqueta es una breve
>   reseña que describe cuándo y por qué una etiqueta se debe utilizar en
>   este sitio específicamente.

La información de este extracto en algunas etiquetas no cumple con lo que se menciona anteriormente, algunas simplemente tienen una copia exacta del primer parrafo de la información de **wiki de etiqueta completa**

Por ejemplo:

- [Wiki de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/mp3/info) [mp3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mp3)
- [Wiki de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/r.net/info) [r.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r.net)
- [Wiki de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/mime/info) [mime](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mime)
- [Wiki de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/gitignore/info) [gitignore](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gitignore)

Entonces de acuerdo a la recomendación que se da en la ayuda, no sería mejor poner algo cómo:

> Se debe usar la etiqueta mp3, cuando la pregunta sea acerca del
>   formato de audio mp3 a traves de procesamiento musical por software o
>   programación de aplicaciones que usen este formato.

Esto para dejar claro cuando se debe usar la etiqueta en el sitio.

Comment: Hola Juan, ya que fuí el que editó dicho extracto, te comento que seguí la segunda recomendación de "La orientación de uso o **extracto de wiki**", es decir "extracto de wiki". Pero es totalmente válido lo que planteas, así que voy a ver con atención las opiniones. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho, no lo sabia, bueno la pregunta es en base a algunas etiquetas que he visto asi, voy a colocar mas ejemplos, :)

Comment: No me molesta para nada que uses este caso cómo ejemplo, al contrario, la duda con respecto al criterio yo también la tengo, usar el concepto de extracto de wiki representa un poco menos de trabajo para ser honestos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho: El "pequeño detalle" (problema) es que el wiki de la etiqueta mp3, al igual que el de muchas otras, no incluye la orientación sobre cómo usar la etiqueta en SOes.

Comment: Es bueno, poner las cosas blanco sobre negro Rubén, como dices muchas de las etiquetas siguen ese criterio, por lo que es fácil suponer que esa es la forma correcta. Ahora ya no tengo excusas.

Comment: Pasó con muchas etiquetas, pero creo que no le hemos dedicado el tiempo para corregirlas. No explicaban __como usar la etiqueta__, sino una especie de resumen de wikipedia. Habrá que hacer una campaña para editarlas.

Comment: Pues creo que somos muy pocos los que hemos leído sobre lo que debe contener el extracto. A diario rechazo el 100% de las ediciones de extracto (con el motivo Carece de orientación de uso), pero creo que la mayoría de los demás usuarios sí las aprueban, por desconocimiento de dicha "regla".

Comment: Se han puesto ejemplos de "malas" etiquetas, pero ¿podríamos indicar "buenas" etiquetas para que sirvan de modelo?

Answer (score 2):

Sí, sería mejor poner algo como lo que propones.

Por cierto el wiki de etiqueta no es un espacio enciclopédico. Sólo se deben incluir definiciones cuando el tema sea altamente especializado o que fuera necesario para desambiguar. El contenido debe orientarse a explicar el uso que se le da la etiqueta en este sitio en particular, por lo que sería conveniente revisar las preguntas en las que se ha incluido dicha etiqueta.

Los detalles se encuentran en el enlace que se incluye en el recuadro, de la página de edición de los wiki de etiqueta, el cual apunta a una artículo de blog en inglés [Redesigned Tags Page](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/), seguramente valdría la pena hacer la traducción.

[image]