# Las Wiki de etiqueta me parecen pobres

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, wiki-de-etiqueta

> me tope con esta discusión [montones de preguntas de baja calidad(Y respuestas igualmente malas)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3192/montones-de-preguntas-de-muy-baja-calidad-y-respuestas-igualmente-malas) y al rato con esta otra [Instauremos una cola de revisión “triaje” para que solo las preguntas con cierto nivel entren en la página de inicio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3200/instauremos-una-cola-de-revisi%c3%b3n-triaje-para-que-solo-las-preguntas-con-cierto)

Soy un miembro **activo** de la comunidad desde solo unos pocos días, pero soy miembro pasivo desde hace un buen rato, seguía a la comunidad leyendo sus respuestas y preguntas sin siquiera iniciar sesión, desde hace unas semanas me tope con un tema que no le encontraba lógica y ni explicación por ninguna parte, eso me animo a tratar de ser parte activa de *StackOverflow* y con el pensamiento y la intensión de seguir siéndolo.

Una de las cosas que me llamo la atención son la wiki de las etiquetas, la cual pensé que era secciones sobre ese tema mucho mas amplios pero son una pequeña información con respecto a ese tema en particular, que es C y quien lo creo, que es PHP y de donde deriva etc.

Si he notado como todo el mundo que hay preguntas las cuales su problema no es que sean malas, el problema es que se ve a leguas que tienen muy poca investigación del autor, no investigan nada sobre el tema y su problema antes de hacer la pregunta, y el primer recurso al que recurren es a realizarla por acá, yéndose después que se la solucionan y no participando en a comunidad de ninguna manera.

Parte de este problema, que me ha pasado en varias ocasiones(con cmake por ejemplo), es que la documentación sobre un tema es muy mala, o demasiado técnica, orientada a un público que se supone que debe tener conocimiento algo avanzados y dejando de lado a las personas que se encuentran con ese tema por primera vez.

Opino que una buena manera de solucionar ese "ataque" de malas preguntas, sin fundamento e investigación, es tener una verdadera Wiki sobre cada etiqueta que ha sido aceptada, con una introducción, e información sobre ese tema en particular. No es volver inventar la rueda o volver a crear la documentación cuando se supone que en las páginas oficiales deberían estar, mas bien es como un complemento a esas documentaciones demasiado técnicas y responder con **anticipación** esas preguntas que son consideradas malas, que de hecho se hacen es por falta de información.

Comment: ¿Consideras que enriquecer la información de cada etiqueta podrá ayudar a los usuarios a realizar mejores preguntas? Cero que ayudaría pero en muy pocos casos dado que si usuarios nuevos se aventuran a preguntar sin siquiera haber revisado *Cómo preguntar* o haber tomado el *Recorrido*. La información de las etiquetas debe ser concisa y precisa, ya si alguien desea profundizar existen la documentación oficial ;)

Comment: Diría que lo que quieres es algo más parecido al difunto [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) (que nosotros nunca llegamos a tener). En lo personal, creo que no mejoraría nada (o muy poco) añadir información más técnica a la wiki de etiqueta. Podría ser útil añadir enlaces a preguntas frecuentes en esa etiqueta, pero como dice @Flxtr, si los usuarios no se leen [ask] o completan el [tour], ¿cómo podemos esperar que lean la wiki de etiqueta? No lo van a hacer.

Comment: Las wikis de las etiquetas son descripciones someras de las tecnologias, y su presentacion es solo para saber en que ambitos se deben usar (la etiqueta, no la tecnologia). No reemplazan ni intentan reemplazar la documentacion real de la tecnologia. Para mi no habria que tocar las wikis, ya que llegado el punto, siempre les va a faltar informacion (y si, suena mucho al extinto documentation)

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente los Wikis de Etiqueta de SOes no son lo que estas pensando. Pero entonces

- ¿qué son?
- ¿cuál es el contenido que deben incluir?

La respuesta oficial está en el artículo de ayuda sobre el privilegio [Usuario de confianza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user):

> ### Wikis de etiquetas
>
> #### ¿Qué son los Wikis de etiquetas ?
>
> Los Wikis de etiquetas son una introducción general a un tema definido
>   por esa etiqueta. Son un lugar para consolidar y formar una
>   sub-comunidad alrededor de una etiqueta. Contienen, entre otras cosas,
>   las preguntas más frecuentes en la etiqueta, los usuarios principales
>   de la etiqueta y las mejores respuestas recientes en la etiqueta.
>
> #### ¿Cuándo debo editar una Wiki de etiqueta?
>
> Cada vez que sientas que la comunidad alrededor de esa etiqueta podría
>   beneficiarse de una buena edición.
>
> #### ¿Cómo edito la Wiki de etiqueta?
>
> Todas las etiquetas activas tienen páginas de descripción breves o "Wikis de etiquetas" en
>
> ```
> /tags/etiqueta/info
> ```
>
> Las descripciones incluyen un breve resumen que se muestra en la
>   página de la etiqueta principal en
>
> ```
> /questions/tagged/etiqueta
> ```
>
> #### ¿Qué sucede cuando se edita la Wiki de etiqueta?
>
> Todos los cambios en el Wiki de etiqueta se guardan en el historial de
>   revisiones, junto con los editores individuales. Siempre se puede ver
>   el historial completo de revisiones haciendo clic en el enlace
>   historial en la parte inferior de la página de información de la
>   etiqueta.
>
> #### ¿Qué debo escribir en la Wiki de etiqueta?
>
> Lee la guía en la [entrada del blog anunciando los wikis de la etiqueta
>   en su forma actual](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) (en inglés). En resumen:
>
> - El extracto es el primer contacto de la etiqueta.
> - Evita definir genéricamente el concepto detrás de una etiqueta, a menos que esté altamente especializada.
> - Concéntrate en lo que significa una etiqueta para su comunidad. Proporciona una guía básica sobre cuándo usar la etiqueta.

**Preguntas y respuestas relacionadas**

- [Edición de wikis de las etiquetas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/96/65)
- [Extractos de etiqueta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2564/65)